# Odd NSString Behavior "warning: Unable to read symbols for..."

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsstring

I have an object that handles database actions.  It initiates with:

```
-(id)init{
    databaseName = @"WhoPaidLast.sql";

    // I think this one gets it from the app whereas the next one gets it from the phone
    // databasePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"WhoPaidLast" ofType:@"sql"];

    // Get the path to the documents directory and append the databaseName
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    self.databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

    // Execute the "checkAndCreateDatabase" function
    [self checkAndCreateDatabase];

    return self;
```

At the end of this I check the db:

```
-(void) checkAndCreateDatabase{
    // Check if the SQL database has already been saved to the users phone, if not then copy it over
    BOOL success;

    // Create a FileManager object, we will use this to check the status
    // of the database and to copy it over if required
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // Check if the database has already been created in the users filesystem
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:self.databasePath];

    // If the database already exists then return without doing anything
    if(success) return;

    // If not then proceed to copy the database from the application to the users filesystem

    // Get the path to the database in the application package
    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

    // Copy the database from the package to the users filesystem
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:self.databasePath error:nil];

    //[fileManager release];
}
```

After this, when I go to use databasePath I only seem to be able to use it once before it throws this error:

```
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.1 (8G4)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib (file not found).
```

I have a function that returns a bunch of values from the database.  The first time detabasePath is used it works fine and outputs the intended value, the second time it throws the above error.

Here is the beginning of that function:

```
// Setup the database object
    sqlite3 *database;

    // Init groupsArray
    groupsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


     NSLog(@"r- %@",self.databasePath);
     NSLog(@"s- %@",self.databasePath);
    // Open the database from the users filessytem
    if(sqlite3_open([self.databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
```

If I remove the second NSLog function then it errors the next time databasePath is used.  If I remove both it'll work for the sqlite3_open function but error on the next use.

If anyone knows the source of my error and/or what I might be doing wrong I'd very much appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There look to be a number of memory-management-related errors in the above code.  I'm guessing that the debugger error you're seeing is due to a memory-related crash that the debugger isn't quite able to latch onto to give you a stack trace.

First off, your `-init` method never calls this on the superclass, which is not right.  You need to have something like

```
if (!(self = [super init]))
{
    return nil;
}
```

at the start of that method.

That alone should lead to all kinds of fun crashes.  Beyond that, make sure that the `databasePath` property is set to use `copy` or `retain` (preferably `copy`, given that it's an NSString), or it won't hold on to the autoreleased object returned by `[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName]`.

Also, I know you have it commented out, but don't use `[fileManager release]`.  That's a shared instance you get back from `[NSFileManager defaultManager]` and you haven't retained it, so releasing that would lead to bad things.

You could try to enable breakpoints and turn NSZombie on to find your specific crash location, but I bet the cause is one of the factors I list above.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug of iOS/ Xcode 4

Enter the following 2 commands in Terminal

```
cd /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.1\ \(8G4\)/Symbols/

sudo ln -s /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/Developer/ Developer
```

Clean (shift+cmd+k) the project before run it. And the problem should solved.

Ref: http://blog.damore.it/2011/04/xcode4-debugging-problem-warning-unable.html